# VBA Userform with Textbox - formatting the text

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, userform, bookmarks

so I'm very new to VBA. I've created a very simple template that when opened, gives me a form to fill out which will insert text into a document through a commandbutton.

I'm trying to take it a step further a bit but am not sure how to go about bringing the code together. To insert the text, I'm using the bookmark feature. On my form, I have 4 Textboxes that act as options. If all 4 are filled in, the text looks like:

Option1Option2Option3Option4

I need it to look like:

Option1, Option2, Option3 and Option4

Not only that but I would like it so that the "and" is added depending on how many textboxes are filled in. For example, if I only have the first two filled it, I need it to look like:

Option1 and Option2

Does that make sense? Below is how it's structured currently. I would appreciate any pointers in moving forward.

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument
        .Bookmarks("Program1").Range.Text = TextBox1.Value
        .Bookmarks("Program2").Range.Text = TextBox2.Value
        .Bookmarks("Program3").Range.Text = TextBox3.Value
        .Bookmarks("program4").Range.Text = TextBox4.Value
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If these bookmarks are contiguous, there is no need for four bookmarks. Add the following module-level variables:

```vb
Private s As String, hasAnd As Boolean
```

Create a `Sub` which prepends the text of a textbox to the private variable, inserting a comma or `and` as appropriate:

```vb
Private Sub AppendText(txt As TextBox)
If Len(txt.Text) = 0 Then Exit Sub

If Len(s) = 0 Then
    s = txt.Text
ElseIf Not hasAnd Then
    hasAnd = True
    s = txt.Text & " and " & s
Else
    s = txt.Text & ", " & s
End If
End Sub
```

Call the subprocedure for each textbox **in reverse order**:

```vb
AppendText TextBox4
AppendText TextBox3
AppendText TextBox2
AppendText TextBox1
```

Then, use the value of `s` as the text of the bookmark:

```vb
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Program1").Range.Text = s
```